# Which kind of basil should I use?

Tags: ingredient-selection, basil

I'm new to cooking and I was planning to make a recipe I saw on TV with pasta. One ingredient is basil. The chef on the show advised always to use fresh herbs; he used a kind of vasiliko with large leaves <del>I think it's called holy basil</del>.

I tried to find one those species but they only grow in spring time. During winter we have a different kind with smaller leaves, it's the second from left to right in the picture.

[image: vasilikos]

Does it make any difference? Should I use this one or skip it and use dry basil?

**Penne with prosciutto and mozzarella:**

> ```
>  300 gr. pence
>  10 cherry tomatoes
>  100 gr. fresh mozzarella
>  1 onion
>  basil leaves
>  10 slices prosciutto
>  olive oil
>  Salt and pepper
> ```

Comment: The different herbs labelled basil do have different flavors.  Can you tell us more about your recipe and what cuisine it is from?

Comment: Holy basil (tulsi) would be very odd to use in that recipe. It's one of the least "basily" basils. For Italian dishes, something like Genovese basil would be a lot more common.

Comment: You can watch the recipe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvTg-429KTo. It's the first, at the second minute. It's in Greek.

Comment: The Platyfylos one looks closest to what I have seen in Italian supermarkets. But I haven't visited many of them, so maybe it is a regional observation only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of Italian recipe, you want a Mediteranian style basil, often called simply "basil" or "sweet basil".

Ones called holy basil or thai basil have a much more aggressive and extremely perfumed flavor which would be jarring in this dish.

[image]

Comment: Should I always skip dry herbs?

Comment: That is a complicated question.  In general, the heartier woodier herbs like oregano do well dried; the delicate herbs like bail or taragon really should e used fresh.  On the other hand, if dry is all you have, it can be better than none.

Comment: In the picture I've add, yours is in the middle. The one I found it's on the left. You can see the difference on the size. Does it makes any difference in taste or am I too peculiar?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read greek and the picture is a little too small for my eyes.  I imagine any one in your market should be able to guide you to regular basil.